# THE PLOTLY GRAPH disappears when func finished executing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The plotly graph doesn't show on button click but when applied breakpoint on the function then it appeared when the function was executing but disappeared when function finished executing.
When the func function is executing the graph corresponding to the value shows up when we apply breakpoint but it doesn't show when the func has finished executing. 
The html file is testfunc.component.html.
The js file id testfunc.component.ts

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, HostListener, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js';
import {Config, Data, Layout} from 'plotly.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-testfunc',
  templateUrl: './testfunc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testfunc.component.css']
})
export class TestfuncComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('plotDiv')
  plotDiv: ElementRef;

@ViewChild('plotDiv2')
  plotDiv2:ElementRef;

@ViewChild('plotDiv3')
  plotDiv3:ElementRef;

@ViewChild('plotDiv4')
  plotDiv4:ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }
    val='Linear';
    public show:boolean = false;
    public buttonNamelog:any = 'Show';
    public buttonNamelinear:any = 'Hide';

   func(event,val){
    console.log(event);
    console.log(val);

      if(val=='Linear')
      {
        console.log("plot hua");
        this.plotLinearCalibrationCurve();
      }

      else if(val=='Log')
       {
        console.log("plot hua 2");
        this.plotLogCalibrationCurve();
       }

    this.val=val;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.show = !this.show;

    if(this.show)  {
      this.plotLinearCalibrationCurve();
      this.buttonNamelog = "Hide";
      this.buttonNamelinear = "Show";
    }
    else{
      this.plotLogCalibrationCurve();
      this.buttonNamelog = "Show";
      this.buttonNamelinear = "Hide";
    }
  }

 plotLinearCalibrationCurve(){ 
   console.log("plot starts");
    let data = [{ x: [1.86847506959731,
                        1.86847506959731,
                        1.90173602675496,
                        1.9086440476136,
                        1.91606063929495,
                        1.9302952476294,
                        1.93324759370438,
                        1.94530437395854,
                        1.98985524850596,
                        2.05414232854343,
                        2.10881882608735,
                        2.33966784509312,
                        2.34111159461593,
                        2.34111159461593,
                        2.46751909076823,
                        3.81121572234882,
                        3.84577288750813,
                        5.22901588560763,
                        6.50540597390556,
                        8.3747069172046
                        ], y: [1.45134311084466, 1.03475496462703, 3.11769569571516, 4.9506835390727,
                          3.42380466555587, 1.72912408674257, 3.01571491752108, 2.05722891070357, 1.19885736718508,
                          2.87957391133716, 2.28451940327991, 2.45115466176696, 2.74743215135693, 2.16554182872015,
                          2.83041651008348, 3.50762220057485, 1.45134311084466, 1.97207829361669, 1.45134311084466,
                          4.22865296404832

                      ],  type: 'scatter', name: '2014', hoverinfo: 'text+x+y',
                                    mode: 'markers', marker: {color: 'rgba(200, 50, 100, .7)', size: 16}
                                  }];

              let layout1 = { 
                  hovermode:'closest',
                  title:'Pathway Enrichment LOG',
                  xaxis:{ hoverformat: '.2r',title:'PATHWAY IMPACT FACTOR',color:'#7672C4',showline:true,zeroline:false, linecolor:'#7672C4'},
                  yaxis:{ hoverformat: '.2r',title:'PVAL',color:'#7672C4',showline:true, zeroline:false, linecolor:'#7672C4'},
                  width:500,
                  height:400,
                  t:0,
                  anchor:'free',
                  position:1,
                  titlefont:{color:"#7672C4"},
                  
                      
              };

          

    Plotly.newPlot(this.plotDiv.nativeElement,data, layout1);
   

            }

            plotLogCalibrationCurve(){
              console.log("plot starts2");

              let data = [{ x: [1.86847506959731,
                1.86847506959731,
                1.90173602675496,
                1.9086440476136,
                1.91606063929495,
                1.9302952476294,
                1.93324759370438,
                1.94530437395854,
                1.98985524850596,
                2.05414232854343,
                2.10881882608735,
                2.33966784509312,
                2.34111159461593,
                2.34111159461593,
                2.46751909076823,
                3.81121572234882,
                3.84577288750813,
                5.22901588560763,
                6.50540597390556,
                8.3747069172046
                ], y: [1.45134311084466, 1.03475496462703, 3.11769569571516, 4.9506835390727,
                  3.42380466555587, 1.72912408674257, 3.01571491752108, 2.05722891070357, 1.19885736718508,
                  2.87957391133716, 2.28451940327991, 2.45115466176696, 2.74743215135693, 2.16554182872015,
                  2.83041651008348, 3.50762220057485, 1.45134311084466, 1.97207829361669, 1.45134311084466,
                  4.22865296404832

              ],  type: 'scatter', name: '2014', hoverinfo: 'text+x+y',
                            mode: 'markers', marker: {color: 'rgba(200, 50, 100, .7)', size: 16}
                          }];
              

              let layout2 = { 
                hovermode:'closest',
                title:'Pathway Enrichment LINEAR',
                xaxis:{ hoverformat: '.2r',title:'PATHWAY IMPACT FACTOR',color:'#7672C4',showline:true,zeroline:false, linecolor:'#7672C4'},
                yaxis:{ hoverformat: '.2r',title:'PVAL',color:'#7672C4',showline:true, zeroline:false, linecolor:'#7672C4'},
                width:500,
                height:400,
                t:0,
                anchor:'free',
                position:1,
                titlefont:{color:"#7672C4"},
              };
                Plotly.newPlot(this.plotDiv2.nativeElement,data, layout2);
                
                    
          

            }
}
```

```html
<button #log value="Log" (click)="func($event,log.value)">Log</button>
<button #linear value="Linear" (click)="func($event,linear.value)">Linear</button>


<ng-container  *ngIf = "val == 'Log'" >
    <p>First</p>
    <div  id="plotDiv" #plotDiv></div>
</ng-container>
   
<ng-container  *ngIf =" val == 'Linear'" >
    <p>Second</p>
    <div id="plotDiv2" #plotDiv2></div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Possibly related to the fact that the template is backwards compared to the code?  If the "Log" button is clicked, you set `this.val` to `"Log"` and output the plot to `plotDiv2`, but when `this.val` is `"Log"`, the template shows `plotDiv` and not `plotDiv2` according to the `ngIf` conditions.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you need more help, it would make it easier if you set up an example that people can play with on a service like [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/).